# Right-justify compound/composite expression in Log4j pattern layout?

Tags: log4j, logback, log4j2

I want my log to look like this:

```
      ClassName.methodName() - just did something
ClassName.methodNameLonger() - just did something else
```

I know you can right-justify just the method name with `%-17M` but I end up with this:

```
ClassName.methodName      () - just did something
ClassName.methodNameLonger() - just did something else
```

Is there a way to justify multiple elements as a single block such that the padding appears only at the very beginning?

I'm not sure it's possible looking at the reference:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

**Further details**

If I try to right-justify the class name, I get:

```
ClassName      .      methodName() - just did something
ClassName      .methodNameLonger() - just did something else
ClassNameLonger.methodNameLonger() - just did something else
```

which isn't terrible, but still it's not able to treat multiple fields (including the literal text `()`) as a contiguous unit to be justified.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure it is an advantage to group the class and method name now that I see it in my log output. Aligning the class names separately looks cleaner in a way. BUT putting the `()` next to the method name is a benefit of compound expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, Log4j does not support this.

---

However, logback does.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" scan="true">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-5level %20(%logger{0}.%method\(\)) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

---

Full documentation here:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Parentheses

**Parentheses are special**

In logback, parentheses within the pattern string are treated as grouping tokens. Thus, it is possible to group a sub-pattern and apply formatting directives on that sub-pattern. As of version `0.9.27`, logback supports composite conversion words such as `%replace` which can transform sub-patterns.

For example, the pattern

```
%-30(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n
```

will group the output generated by the sub-pattern `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]` so that it is right-padded if less than 30 characters.

If without the grouping the output was

```
13:09:30 [main] DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Classload hashcode is 13995234
13:09:30 [main] DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Initializing for ServletContext
13:09:30 [main] DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Trying platform Mbean server
13:09:30 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  ch.qos.logback.demo.LoggingTask - Howdydy-diddly-ho - 0
13:09:38 [btpool0-7] INFO c.q.l.demo.lottery.LotteryAction - Number: 50 was tried.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7] INFO c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Beginning to factor.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7] DEBUG c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Trying 2 as a factor.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7] INFO c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Found factor 2
```

with the `"%-30()"` grouping it would be

```
13:09:30 [main]            DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Classload hashcode is 13995234
13:09:30 [main]            DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Initializing for ServletContext
13:09:30 [main]            DEBUG c.q.logback.demo.ContextListener - Trying platform Mbean server
13:09:30 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  ch.qos.logback.demo.LoggingTask - Howdydy-diddly-ho - 0
13:09:38 [btpool0-7]       INFO  c.q.l.demo.lottery.LotteryAction - Number: 50 was tried.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7]       INFO  c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Beginning to factor.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7]       DEBUG c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Trying 2 as a factor.
13:09:40 [btpool0-7]       INFO  c.q.l.d.prime.NumberCruncherImpl - Found factor 2
```

The latter form is more comfortable to read.

If you need to treat the parenthesis character as a literal, it needs to be escaped by preceding each parenthesis with a backslash. As in, `\(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]\)`.

Answer (score 2):

This can definitely be done in log4j 2

You can place the entire compound expression in a %replace pattern (with no parameters) and then justify the result of the %replace

Thus if I want to justify the composite expression `[%c{1}:%method:%line]`

I would simply dump the expression in an empty replace and right justify that as follows

`%-40.40replace{[%c{1}:%method:%line]}{}{}`

And the result is a grouped expression truncated/expanded to exactly 40 characters and right justified (or `%-40.-40replace` for left-justified)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right-justifying the class name? `%-20C{1}.%17M`

Comment: I don't see it, the question looks unchanged. Have you tried right-justifying the class name? `%-20C{1}.%17M`

Comment: I didn't update my post, I updated your post since it's only relevant to your question. Maybe my edits aren't visible to you until they've been approved. I'll update my original post now....

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Hmm, the alignment/justification is done on a per element basis in the code. We would need to introduce a class+method conversion specifier to support your request. If you really want this I suggest raising a feature request on log4j2's Jira issue tracker, and providing a patch yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.